# Remove first word from the WooCommerce product title

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

Is it possible to remove the first word from the product title in WooCommerce? I've found some php code but I can't figure it out at the moment.

```
echo substr(strstr("Remove First Word"," "), 1);
```

That should echo "First Word". How would I do that for the WooCommerce product title? I appreciate all the help!

Comment: Yes it is, first of. Where do you want to serve the product title? Checkout? Product list? Product page?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Yvan. It should work on every frontend page.

Comment: @Fluxec, see my answer on how to do the first word remove.

Comment: @Fluxec The product title uses Wordpress function get_the_title() or the_title() to be displayed (as woocommerce product is a custom post type)… so the correct hook to be used is "the_title", see my answer please.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you LoicTheAztec. I've answered below.

Comment: Thank all of you for your help! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For product title in single product pages and archives pages:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'custom_the_title', 10, 2 );
function custom_the_title( $title, $post_id ){
    $post_type = get_post_field( 'post_type', $post_id, true );
    if( $post_type == 'product' || $post_type == 'product_variation' )
        $title = substr( strstr( $title, ' ' ), 1 );

    return $title;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works.

> The product title uses WordPress function `get_the_title()` or `the_title()` to be displayed (as woocommerce product is a custom post type)… so the correct filter hook to be used is `"the_title"`.

But it will not really handle html tags (as this are something else in the templates).

---

For cart and checkout pages:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'customizing_cart_item_name', 10, 3);
function customizing_cart_item_name( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    $product = $cart_item['data'];
    $product_permalink = $product->is_visible() ? $product->get_permalink( $cart_item ) : '';

    $product_name = $product->get_name();
    $product_name = substr( strstr( $product_name, ' ' ), 1 );

    if ( $product_permalink && is_cart() ) {
        return sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $product_name );
    } elseif ( ! $product_permalink && is_cart() ) {
        return $product_name . '&nbsp;';
    } else {
        return $product_name;
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
  $str = "Remove First Word";
  $words = explode(' ', $str);
  unset($words[0]);
  echo join(' ', $words);
```

The [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) function returns an array with each words.

The [`unset`](http://php.net/unset) function remove the first word contained in the array `$words`.

Finally, [`join`](http://php.net/join) print all `$words` joined by space .

[demo](https://eval.in/952208)

Comment: Thank you. I'll test yours as soon as I setup the other woocommerce part.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using this?

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title' ) ) {

    /**
    * Removes first word in WooCommerce product_title
    * @var $tag
    */
    function woocommerce_template_loop_product_title() {
        $tag = is_product_taxonomy() || is_shop() ? 'h2' : 'h3';

        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', '<' . $tag . ' class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">' . substr(strstr(get_the_title()," "), 1) . '</' . $tag . '>');
    }

    /**
     * Removes first word in WooCommerce product page product_title
     * @var $tag
     */
    function woocommerce_single_product_summary() {
        $tag = 'h1';

        echo apply_filters(woocommerce_single_product_summary, '<' . $tag . ' class="product_title entry-title">' . substr(strstr(get_the_title()," "), 1) . '</' . $tag . '>');
    }
}
```

Hopefully this works out for you, haven't tested it.

Comment: Thank you Ivan. It works on some pages. Unfortunately it doesn't work on the product page itself.

Comment: Ah, I will take another hook function !

Comment: I guess it doesn't work as I've a 'h1'-tag for the product title on the product page. :/ Is it possible to cover all the h-tags?

Comment: @Fluxec Edited my post

Comment: Hm maybe I'm stuck with my brain somehow but I can't get it to work with the code you supplied.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm still checking why it still shows the full title.